# Use Isotope with objects loaded in with XML and jQuery. Is this possible?

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-isotope

I have objects I am loading in with XML and jQuery and trying to hook on to Isotope, but is seems it's a no go. Is this possible? I've tried many different solutions but can't seem to find one that works. This is what I have. I've tried a callback function in isotope, but still no luck.. I am calling in my class with the XML and the result is this in firebug: **item yellow, item red**, **item blue**, etc.

```
    var $container = $('#container');
    var $checkboxes = $('#filters a');

    $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    transformsEnabled: false,
    animationOptions: {
    duration: 4000,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
    queue: false,
    complete: complete()
    }
    });


    function complete(){
           $.get('sites.xml', function (d) {

    $(d).find('site').each(function () {
        // var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var imageUrl = $(this).find('imgurl').text();
        var title = $(this).find('title').text();
        var url = $(this).find('url').text();
        var brief = $(this).find('brief').text();
        var long = $(this).find('long').text();
        var classa = $(this).find('_class').text();

    $('<div class="' + classa + '"></div>').html('<a href="' + url + '"> 
        <img  src="' + imageUrl + '" class="thumbnail" />' + '<h1>' + title + '</h1> 
        </a>').appendTo('#container');

        });

     });

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you are adding your elements to the container **after** the animation is completed.
I think it has to be the other way around:
on page ready:

- do your ajax
- in the success-callback add the elements to the DOM
- then initialize isotope (last step in the ajax-success)

edit:
to your question in the comment:
I'm not sure if I understand what your asking for.
Since there is no jsfiddle or something I had to make sum assumptions:

- your container is empty
- you load some xml, parse it and generate elements you want to have in isotope
- your code looks like you initialize isotope on an empty container - then add elements.

my solution:

```
var $container = $('#container');
var $checkboxes = $('#filters a');

init();

function init(){
    $.get('sites.xml', function (d) {

        $(d).find('site').each(function () {
            var imageUrl = $(this).find('imgurl').text();
            var title = $(this).find('title').text();
            var url = $(this).find('url').text();
            var brief = $(this).find('brief').text();
            var long = $(this).find('long').text();
            var classa = $(this).find('_class').text();

            $('<div class="' + classa + '"></div>').html('<a href="' + url + '"> 
            <img  src="' + imageUrl + '" class="thumbnail" />' + '<h1>' + title + '</h1> 
            </a>').appendTo('#container');

            }); // end each

        initIsotop(); // after adding all elements - init isotop
    }); // end $.get
}

function initIsotop() {
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        transformsEnabled: false,    
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 4000,
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
            queue: false
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How would I add a success or complete function to the way I have my XML setup?