# How to apply a default filter to the container after dynamic insertion of items using Jquery Isotope plugin?

Tags: jquery, filter, jquery-isotope

I'm using the Isotope Plugin. I have an empty container to which I am adding items on `$(document).ready(...`

All those items are added correctly and isotope's layout and filtering on links are working perfectly.

However, I would like to be able to apply a filter on a certain item class directly after they are appended to the container, or even better, during the insertion.

How to do that?

To resume, I have a '.home' filter that I would like to be applied once all items are appended to the container in stead of needing to click a "home" filter.

Comment: And - did the answer below help in some respect?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Thans a lot for your help but I'm sorry it did not help, see my comment bellow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have something simple like

```
<ul id="filters">
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".home">Show all</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".what">What?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".when">When?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".why">Why?</a></li>
    // and so forth...
</ul>
```

you could just run a function to preset filtering, once the DOM has been fully constructed

```
$(function() {
    // Isotope stuff...
    $container.isotope({filter: '.home'});
    // more Isotope stuff...
});
```

and Isotope has been initialised. See [this modified DeSandro fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RRgjD/) in which the initial view is filtered to show only the red elements.

**UPDATE** Loading the initial content into an empty #container (via Ajax?), you could use the [insert method](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/adding-items.html) or just hide the #container until all elements have been loaded and sorted. Regarding Ajax and initialising Isotope on success, see also [this SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9657833/963514).

Comment: Hello, 
sorry but this is not answering my question as in DeSandro's example, items are already in the container.
In my case, the container is empty and I am adding items dynamically.
What I would like is to apply the filter while adding the items or just after that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Although I suggest the insert method to add items (because of pre-filtering/pre-sorting), it would be useful to see your sandbox or fiddle as to how your page is supposed to work with an initially empty #container.

Comment: Hello, the initIsotop function describer in the link you provided (see UPDATE) did the trick!
Thanks a lot!
I have not enough reputation to vote up but I'll definitely come back to increase your reputation when I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 4):

You can use isotope initial options.

Please check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/mohamad-abouasy/pen/XogPPm) which is based on the official example of "[Combination filters](http://isotope.metafizzy.co.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/filtering.html#combination-filters)".

```
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.color-shape',
  filter: '.initial-filter-class' //use this class with the items you want to load initially.
});
```

For example:

```
  <div class="color-shape small round red initial-filter-class"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the party, but I had the same question when I was working with Isotope yesterday and ended up solving it a different way.

Let's say I have a group of filter buttons, much like what Systembolaget had:

```
<div id="filters">
  <button data-filter="*">Show all</button>
  <button data-filter=".hidden">Archived</button>
  <button data-filter="*:not(.hidden)">Current</button>
</div>
```

Perhaps I want to only show the "Current" filter when a user finishes loading the page. I set a variable to the CSS selector matching the filter I wanted. We'll use this variable later.

```
var $grid;
var filterValue = "*:not(.hidden)";
```

Next, I need to initialize my content. I already had my content ready to go so I skipped this step, but you could use a JavaScript Promise if you're planning on loading the content asynchronously.

This is an example I took from [Google's Promise introduction article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises):

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var content = [];

  // do a thing, possibly async, then…

  if (content.length > 0) {
    resolve(content);
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("Nothing loaded"));
  }
});
```

Here's the function I used to set-up the isotope grid and event listener:

```
function init() {
  // Initialize isotope and the filter method we want to use
  $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    filter: function() {
      return filterValue ? $(this).is(filterValue) : true;
    }
  });

  // Event listener for the filter buttons
  $('#filters').on('click', 'button', function() {
    filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');

    $(this).addClass('active')
           .siblings().removeClass('active');

    // Refresh the isotope grid to display the filtered items
    $grid.isotope();
  });
}
```

Once you've defined what the promise should do, you can initialize your isotope grid. You'll need to nest it within the `then` method so that it only runs once the promise has successfully resolved. This also allows you to set-up any fallbacks that should run in the case where your content-loading step fails.

```
promise.then(function(results) {

  // Function defined in the last code snippet
  return init();

}, function(err) {
  // Error: "Nothing loaded"
  console.log(err); 

  // If you have a banner hidden on the page, you can display it
  $('.message').show();
});
```

If you don't need to use a promise (like in my case), then all you need to do is this:

```
init();
```